# Is it possible to "split bars" in barplot with R?

Tags: r

I have a barplot beside = T. What I need is to split (or draw an horizontal line) at each height "marks" of each bars.

Sample matrix to plot :

```
    > head(top.fem)
        FD1 FE2 FF1
    J01   2   2  10
    J02   4   0   0
    J03   6   2   5
    J04   1   6   3
    J05  10  10   2
    J06   9   6   5
```

I simply :

```
barplot(top.fem,beside = T)
```

So, for FD1,  bar 1 has a height of 2, bar 2 height of 1 and bar 3 height of 6 ect... How to split bar 1 in two, bar two in 4 and bar 3 in 6 ? The results would "look like" a stacked bar plot but it is not. Am I being clear ?

Thanx for any help !

Comment: Err - could you please give a small reproducible example (ie some small amount of data + code) of how you currently make your barplot?

Comment: Or - say we had `barplot(VADeaths,beside=T)` (you should have that dataset already). How would you modify this to get what you want?

Comment: Ok, I edited my question, might be clearer.

Comment: In barplot(VADeaths, besides = T), say there is no decimals values, for rural male, bar one would be split in 11, bar 2 in 18, bar 3 in 26 ect...

Comment: Link to related ggplot2 question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701485/r-graphs-creating-tuftes-horizontal-bar-lines#comment18847236_13701485

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add horizontal lines on the whole picture: if they are white, and if the background is white, they will remain unnoticed.

```
barplot(VADeaths, beside=TRUE, las=1)
abline(h=0:100, col="white")
barplot(
  VADeaths, beside=TRUE, las=1,
  add=TRUE, col=FALSE
)
```

[image: barplot]

Comment: Yes, great idea! It looks very nice on my plot. Great idea once again !