# Make histograms of stacked rectangles rather than columns

Tags: r

With the following code, I get a histogram as below

```
x <- rnorm(100)
hist(x,col="gray")
```

What can I do to get to display the bars as stacked rectangles (visible by their outlines, rather than a change in fill color) instead of uniform columns? Each rectangle represents a frequency of, for example, 1, although I want to be able to change this through a parameter.

[image: histogram]

Comment: you might be able to adapt `plotrix::symbolbarplot` to do this ...

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527802/is-it-possible-to-split-bars-in-barplot-with-r

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd I'd prefer to have control over the colors but yes, your solution solves my problem for the most part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function to get you started (it is actually a modicication of part of the examples for the `tkBrush` function in the `TeachingDemos` package):

```
     rechist <- function(x,...){
         tmp <- hist(x,plot=F)
         br <- tmp$breaks
         w <- as.numeric(cut(x,br,include.lowest=TRUE))
         sy <- unlist(lapply(tmp$counts,function(x)seq(length=x)))
         my <- max(sy)
         sy <- sy/my
         my <- 1/my
         sy <- sy[order(order(x))]
        plot.new()
        plot.window(xlim=range(br), ylim=c(0,1))
         rect(br[w], sy-my, br[w+1], sy, 
            border=TRUE, col='grey')
         rect(br[-length(br)], 0, br[-1], tmp$counts*my)
        axis(1)
     }

rechist( iris$Petal.Length )
```

Answer (score 2):

From answer at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527802/is-it-possible-to-split-bars-in-barplot-with-r) (h/t Vincent Zoonekynd).

```
x <- rnorm(100)
hist(x,col="gray")
abline(h=seq(5,40,5),col="white")
```