# Confining x-axis span of abline in R

Tags: r, plot

In relation to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893696/make-histograms-of-stacked-rectangles-rather-than-columns), I have a plot for which the `xlim` is say `c(0,1000)`. How can I confine each of the lines resulting from

```
abline(h=seq(0,45,5),col="white")
```

to a width of 0 to 500 along the x-axis, while retaining the plot's `xlim` of `c(0,1000)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of `?lines`.

```
plot(1:100)
sapply(seq(1,100,5), function(i) lines(c(0,50), c(i,i)))
```