# How does one creates a `ggplot2` plot that is composed of stacked squares?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, visualization, data-visualization

I would like to use R to create a plot (preferably with `ggplo2`) that looks like this one:
[image: plot illustration]

In this plot, every bar is composed of various numbers of squares, when each square designates a given amount.

The only way I could think of was to create stacked barchart (like the one depicted below) and putting horizontal lines above the plot. But this looks pretty awkward to me.

**EDIT** Commenters to this question and a pointer to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701485/r-graphs-creating-tuftes-horizontal-bar-lines) suggest that placing horizontal lines IS the way to solve my problem. However, what happens if one want to use buildig blocks other than squares such as circles, small pictograms etc?

Comment: You might be able to do it with a combination of `%%`, `%*%` and `geom_rect`.

Comment: I made a plot like this for an experiment at work recently, and a key (I think) is in realizing that you can simply draw lines over the top of your bars to break them up, like you mention.  Change the theme to have a consistent background color (like white) and draw thick lines of the same color over the top of your bars.  As long as you do it in regular intervals, there is no reason to have any background grid lines for reading values.

Comment: @sebastian-c can you please give a link or two for what you mean? (it is very hard to google for "%*%" :-)